# HTTP Header Stylesheets

Tags: php, http, stylesheet

According to this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.6
I can link stylesheets directly in the http header. 
In php it would look like this:

```
header('Link: <http://www.acme.com/corporate.css>; REL=stylesheet');
```

are there any drawbacks in doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main drawback is that it only works in Firefox and Opera. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/httplink/.

Comment: +1 I see your name is all over the spec. http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/browser/draft-ietf-httpbis/12

Answer (score 2):

> are there any drawbacks in doing this?

Debugging styling issues gets a little harder I guess. You can't directly see from the html source of a page what external styles get included.

Comment: I still see them being requested in firebug

Comment: I didn't decline that, did I? It's just you have to check one more thing when working on the styling of a site when you use this header. I'm not a fan of this, since headers are meant to describe the content and the delivery of that, not interfere with it. If a browser doesn't support the header, your content will look different.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you did. If your browser does not support something obviously it's going to look different, I'm saying from a practical standpoint the headers get sent first, so if you included all styles like this it would ensure that stylesheets get loaded before the scripts in messy real life environments. This is just random thought, you don't need to take it seriously, it's just interesting to see that it's possible to include stylesheets like that, whether it's easier to debug is then up to the users preferred debugging style.

Comment: You're right, but the fact that they get sent before the content doesn't guarantee they get applied to the html before stylesheets that are included in the html.

Comment: hmm interesting, too bad it requires me to check in exactly what order they get loaded. :)

Comment: Why doing it easier when you can do it harder?... The head element in the document has a purpose in life, do not betray its tao and set the reference to stylesheets there, so your brothers in the tao will be able to debug it and maintain it later in time :)

Comment: Alfabravo: the obvious *advantage* is that you don't need to modify static files just to change the styling; in some cases it can also be easier for dynamic XML content (such when produced by JAXB).

Comment: @JulianReschke you only can supply the URI to the stylesheet, so the fact that the style information resides in a file doesn't change.

Comment: AlfaBravo: you don't need to change the files that *refer* to the stylesheet; for instance, you can set the CSS for a whole file hierarchy by reconfiguring a single piece of your web server,

Comment: ... while you can do the same by simply altering the `<head>` section of your "master template". :-)

Comment: Codecaster: yes, if there is such a thing.

Comment: @Julian Reschke thanks for popping up, the dynamic XML, and file hierarchy example greatly explain the purpose of http header stylesheets :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 1.1 doesn't support this feature from what I can see:

> This section only applies to user agents conforming to versions of
>   HTTP that define a Link header field. **Note that HTTP 1.1 as defined by
>   [RFC2616] does not include a Link header field** (refer to section
>   19.6.3).

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.6

Comment: Seems to work in all the browsers, but I guess this is reason enough not to use it.

Comment: Treffynon: RFC 2616 is ancient (1999). See RFC 5988. In particular, the HTTP spec does /not/ contain a complete list of header field, that's what the IANA registry is for: http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/perm-headers.html

Comment: Interesting development. @Julian Reschke why not post an answer?

Comment: @JulianReschke I was unaware of the new proposed standard and was merely following the guidance from W3.

Comment: Treffynnon - the W3C has no say in this. The HTTP spec is owned by the IETF (yes, there's collaboration all over the place, including the authors, but that doesn't affect the normative state)

Answer (score -1):

Note that HTTP 1.1 as defined by  [RFC2616] **does not include a Link header field**

Comment: RFC 2616 is ancient (1999). See RFC 5988. In particular, the HTTP spec does /not/ contain a complete list of header field, that's what the IANA registry is for: iana.org/assignments/message-headers/perm-headers.html