# Adding favicon through a http header

Tags: html, http-headers, favicon

Let's assume that I want to add a favicon on a dynamically generated page (specifically an ADF Faces page, but this is irrelevant). I can't modify a  tag of my resulted html.
So I try to add a http-header in servlet header. I want my header to be identical to html head element:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://foo.com/favicon.ico">
```

I'm adding it this way:

```
httpResponse.addHeader("Link", "<http://foo.com/favicon.ico>; rel=\"shortcut icon\"");
```

And in my browser I see this header in response:

```
Link: <http://foo.com/favicon.ico>; rel="shortcut icon"
```

But, unfortunately, this does not have any effect in IE or Chrome. Anyone tried to achieve the same thing? Am I doing something wrong? Is that should work at all?

Comment: Is the `Link:` header a part of HTTP standards? I found [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/9707-link-header.html) but it clearly says that it is a "draft".

Comment: There is a link on wikipedia: [RFC 5988](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988)

Comment: Oooh... Proposed standard... I didn't noticed :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the answer is: this method relies on proposed standard (a draft) that is not implemented yet (thanks to [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) for pointing this out).
Though it would be great if it worked.

Comment: Partly landed in Chrome: https://crbug.com/58456

Comment: It partly landed in 2017, but doesn't support rel="icon", so it won't help with this question. the proposed standard doesn't mention "icon" but I'm not sure we should expect it to.

Answer (score 4):

Yes Link headers have been a defined standard in [RFC 5988](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5988/) since October 2010 but the only [link relation](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml) I've seen working are for stylesheet and only in some browsers at that.

Also see: [HTTP Header Stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091996/http-header-stylesheets)

What @dragn is suggesting is perfectly viable, and in spec why the browsers aren't adopting is beyond me. There are some other useful relations like prefetch, bookmark and glossary to name a few. The least they could do is notify the user that links exist and provide it as a drop down or menu. Maybe a plugin is what is called for to show the browser vendors what we want it to do as it seems they are all confused. Any suggestions?

For now I guess we have to wait till 2020 for this feature to become available which seems to be the trent.

Comment: It's 2020! Any idea if this is supposed to work now?

Comment: @zone117x Apparently implemented partly in Google Chrome: https://crbug.com/58456

Comment: It partly landed in 2017, but doesn't support rel="icon", so it won't help with this question. the proposed standard doesn't mention "icon" but I'm not sure we should expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

## *Yeah yeah "**draft**"..*

anyway..

### If you want to see how you can use it *in-Practice*, here is an example <sub>(taken from [icompile.eladkarako.com](http://icompile.eladkarako.com))</sub>

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Link <http://icompile.eladkarako.com/favicon.ico>; REL="shortcut icon"; TYPE="image/x-icon"
  Header set Link <http://icompile.eladkarako.com/favicon.ico>; REL="icon"; TYPE="image/x-icon"
  Header set Link <http://icompile.eladkarako.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png>; REL="apple-touch-icon"; TYPE="image/png"; sizes="316x316"
</ifModule>
```

It will work in current Chromium/Google Chrome/Google Canary,

(and for sure if you set the switch for `advance web-features` in `chrome://flags`)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in current version of Chrome (September 2016)