# Icon for browser tab with PDF file from Java stream

Tags: java, pdf, tomcat7, outputstream

On a web-page I have a link to a PDF file. On clicking, I am downloading that file from configured external URL into InputStream and then write it into ServletOutputStream. Default browser (at least Chrome and Firefox I think) behaviour after that it to open that PDF file in a new tab. My question is, can i set some icon for that new tab? Because currently it has just a Tomcat icon.

Code for Controller that handles the request:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/pdfGuide")
public void getPdfGuide(HttpServletResponse response, Principal principal) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String urlString = configKeyValuePropsLPSRepository.findByParamKey(PDF_GUIDE_URL).getParamValue();
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format(URL_MALFORMED, urlString), e);
        return;
    }

    try (InputStream input = url.openStream() /* get PDF file from configured location */) {
        if (input != null) {

            byte[] fileContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);

            // set all needed properties and headers for opening the file
            response.setContentType(MediaType.PDF.toString());
            response.addHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION, DISPOSITION_INLINE + ETLUtil.getConfigProperty(
                    PDF_GUIDE_FILE_NAME));
            response.setContentLength(fileContent.length);

            // add file to the output stream of the response
            try (ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream()) {
                output.write(fileContent);
                output.flush();
            }

            LOGGER.info(String.format("User [%s] has opened PDF guide. File size is %d KB. Time taken: %d ms.",
                    principal.getName(), fileContent.length / BYTES_IN_KB, System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while trying to download PDF guide", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Tomcat icon is fetched from `http://your_server/favicon.ico`. You can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227661/adding-favicon-through-a-http-header

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed that icon initially, but it had no effect for me. The problem turned out to be with browser, since it cached the icon. First I cleared 'Cached images and files' in Chrome, but it did not help, so i assumed it was not the problem. But later I also cleared 'Hosted app data' and after that the icon was changed.