Favicon not showing for PDFs on Github
I am using clickfunnels for my website. However they don't allow one to show yourcustomdomain.com in the url of presented PDFS. So I came to Github and bought mydomainname.download as opposed to the dotcom I use on Clickfunnels. Okay.
I have everything working and can show the domain now in the url when someone opens the pdf, before downloading. I am only missing it have the favicon show up. I have been on this for two weeks now. Seriously, there doesn't appear to be a single working conclusion, that I can find.
My OS in Windows 11 Pro, not that I feel it is relevant, but I keep being asked this, (one can edit directly inside github), so I don't get the point of the question, nevertheless I am using Windows 11 Pro.
There is no error message, the favicon simply does not show up for PDFs, but does for home page which is really the 404 page and 404 page has the same code as home page. But the favicon works just fine with these.
Somehow, I presume that somewhere I should be stating via code, that pdfs should present the favicon because it isn't a normal HTML page? However I wouldn't have clue where to start, but I have concluded this somehow to be the case. Please provide exact code, and exactly where to input it. I will list my exact domain name and my user name on github.
https://powerfulxmarketing.download
Link to one of the PDFs: https://powerfulxmarketing.download/Marketing1.pdf
Username on Github: thealainpaul
Has anyone else got this issue or is it just me? If just me, how do you do it?

You're telling the page what favicon to use via <link> tag:
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thealainpaul/thealainpaul.github.io/main/Favicon.ico">

This doesn't work the same when viewing a PDF in the browser, because PDF files do not have the same support for <link> tags.
You need to have the file available in the domain's root, in a file called favicon.ico.
I.e. https://powerfulxmarketing.download/favicon.ico should provide the icon image and only the icon image.
Bonus: Once you get the file in place, you can remove the <link> tag from your HTML.

Oh I see, I get it... Okay let me see how to do that then.

When having a custom domain, how would you put it in the domain root?

@AlainPaul I'd need more information about how your domain is set up, as that's not apparent to me. But, wherever it's hosted, try placing favicon.ico alongside whatever file loads up when you visit your root page (index.html maybe?).

My index.html is in the root, but this is in a subdomain on github. Which I discovered is only possible by repeating your username, in my case my user name is thealainpaul.github.io so when I created a respository called thealainpaul.github.io this created a subdomain. I then purchased domain, I verified the domain, in settings, page. Then I went to My Repositories, settings, pages and I added the custom domain to the aformetnioned, it wouldn't work any other way. I hope this answers the question. I see that everything is committed to root, which is also where favicon is beside index.html file

you could try a Link header but not sure if it works!

Thanks Evert I tried this, this is how it is setup. @amphetamachine I hope I provided enough information. Best

I think @Evert means a Link: ... HTTP response header, but I've never heard of this ever working. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227661/237955 for a discussion about using this.

Ah too bad it's not working! seems like a great case for it.

Thanks guys for the attempts, yes this isn't working... Well it works for everything, just not the pdfs. But the whole point of this is just for the pdfs... So... Anyways, eventually I will find a solution but for now I have to move on from this...

True I could remove the tag and it still works, but unfortunately still not with the pdfs. I believe I need to put code to tell it to do it for the pdfs, especially because the pdfs aren't html code or a normal web page, they are a pdf, the issue is I simply don't know coding, but I saw an article that mentioned this, infprtunately the code wasn't provided as the solution, just the theory.

Anyone else to have a go at this issue? I will truly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Chatgpt said to create separate html files for each pdf and create redirect links. It professes that normally this works. But I am unable to get it to work. The favicon is in the route and the code is as follows:

`





Redirecting to Marketing1.pdf...



If you are not redirected, click here to view Marketing1.pdf.

`
I solved it with the help of Chatgpt

I did it through iframe and created three separate .html files for each pdf. I got help from chatgpt, which even created the full code for me and directed me step by step as I requested.
This was the code for one of the three PDFs:
(Note: once this is uploaded to Github the url is no longer .pdf but .html. I created these in notepad and called the files Marketing1.html and uploaded it to github and Marketing2.html as well as Marketing3.html) (Further Note: The files these serve need to have the actual PDF files in the root directory or in the approriate directory for it to serve.)
Example: powerfulxmarketing.download/Marketing1.pdf now becomes powerfulxmarketing.download/Marketing1.html
Last but not least, as most will probably know, anyways, the favicon also needs to be in the root or appropriately directed/pointed to by the coding. Not sure what terminology to use but I think you get the idea.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thealainpaul/thealainpaul.github.io/main/Favicon.ico">
    <title>Marketing 1</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="Marketing1.pdf" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
</body>
</html>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
